# Values of a linear transformation without explicit formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $T\colon V\to V$ a linear transformation such that  $T(5\vec{v_1}+3\vec{v_2})=−5\vec{v_1}+5\vec{v_2}$ and $T(3\vec{v_1}+2\vec{v_2})=−5\vec{v_1}1+2\vec{v_2}$. Then

\begin{align}
T(\vec{v_1})  & = 5\vec{v_1} + 4\vec{v_2} \\
T(\vec{v_2}) & = \,?\vec{v_1} + -5\vec{v_2} \\
T(4\vec{v_1} - 4\vec{v_2}) & = \,?\vec{v_1} + ?\vec{v_2}
\end{align}

Can someone give me a hand on how to solve these problems, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You know that $T(av+bw)=aT(v)+bT(w)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=5v_1+3v_2$ and $w=3v_1+2v_2$. Then solve for $v_1$ and $v_2$ in terms of $u$ and $w$ to get
\begin{align*}
v_1 & = 2u-2w\\
v_2 & = -2u+5w
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
T(v_1) & =2T(u)-2T(w)\\
T(v_2) & = -2T(u)+5T(w)
\end{align*}
You are already given what are $T(u)$ and $T(w)$.